# Given nonempty sets S and T, does there exist a set R that is disjoint from S with |R|=|T|?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty sets. I would like to show that there exists a set $R$ such that $S\cap R=\emptyset$ and $\left\vert T\right\vert = \left\vert R\right\vert$. Here is my work so far. Let $F_S$ and $F_T$ denote the free groups on $S$ and $T$, respectively, and consider the free product $F_S\ast F_T$. Fix $s_0\in S$, and define a mapping 
\begin{align*}
f:T\to F_S\ast F_T
\end{align*}
by 
\begin{align*}
f(t)=s_0t
\end{align*}
for all $t\in T$. Then $f$ is one-to-one, since $f(t)=f(t')\implies s_0t=s_0t' \implies t=t'$. Hence, $f:T\to f(T)$ is a bijection. Now, I'd like to take $R=f(T)$, so I need to show that $S\cap f(T)=\emptyset$. But this seems true: If there exists some $s\in S\cap f(T)$, then $s=s_0t$ for some $t\in T$. But the word length of $s$ is 1, whereas the word length of $s_0t$ is 2; hence, these elements cannot be equal. Is this reasoning correct? And if so, is there a simpler way to establish this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=T\times\{S\}.$ By folding in $\{S\}$, we've made each element of $R$ "too big" to also be an element of $S$. (One way to make precise this notion of "too big" is the following: the transitive closure of any element of $R$ is strictly larger than the transitive closure of any element of $S$.)

Note that we've used implicitly a non-trivial fact about set theory: that no element of a set $S$ can be of the form $(a, S)$. This is a consequence of the axiom of foundation. In set theories without foundation, this argument doesn't work, and in fact the theorem need not be true: for instance, if there is a "set of all sets" (as in $NF$), then taking that set to be $S$ yields a counterexample.

Comment: I'm still digesting this. Just curious, though: Does my original argument work as well? I'm not very familiar with free group constructions, so it's hard for me to be sure.

Comment: The argument you give doesn't work, now that I look at it, albeit for silly reasons: suppose $S$ is a "mixed" set: for instance, it contains elements $a$ and $b$, but also the element $\langle a, b\rangle$, the sequence of length two consisting of $a$ and $b$. Now, what should the free group on $S$ look like? The problem is $\langle a, b\rangle$ - as a generator - is indistinguishable from the word $ab$. For a concrete example, what is "the free group on the set of finite strings of zeroes and ones?" (cont'd)

Comment: Essentially, the issue is that - since "word" means "sequence," and "sequence" is already a set-theoretic notion - there's no reason something can't be a sequence of length 2 and a sequence of length 1 at the same time. For a concrete example (using Kuratowski pairing): does the set $\{a, \{a, \{b, \{b, c\}\}\}\}$ represent the sequence $\langle a, b, c\rangle$ of length 3 or the sequence $\langle a, \{b, \{b, c\}\}\rangle$ of length 2?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is another approach](http://addoergosum.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/constructing-set-disjoint-from-and.html) that doesn't appeal to the axiom of foundation.

It gives a direct construction, for any set $S$, of another set $R$ such that $|S|=|R|$ and $S \cap R= \emptyset$.

As for your problem, the construction in the link is for the case when $S=T$.

For all remaining cases of the relationship between $S$ and $T$ the method described below will work.

Use the construction in the link to give you an $R$ for $S \cup T$. Then $R$ being disjoint form $S \cup T$ implies that $R$ is disjoint from all subsets of $S \cup T$; in particular $S$. It also follows that all of the subsets of $R$ are disjoint form $S$. In particular that subset $R' \subset R$ such that $|R'|=|T|$.

We don't need to construct such an $R'$ since only a proof of its existence is required. So we're done.